# Chrome Extension, making content script run on all pages?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I want a chrome extension which changes the highlight color of each website to red, I am good on the CSS bit, although, im not sure how to make it work on all pages. This is my current code:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "CustomizeMore",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Customize contents on a webpage!",

  "content_scripts": [{
    "css": ["main.css"],
    "js": ["main.js"],
    "matches": ["http://*/*"]
   }]


}
```

Currently, it runs on sites with HTTP but not ones with HTTPS. How do I make it run on sites that utilize either HTTP or HTTPS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is in your `"matches"` defintion, you've only defined it to match pages beginning with the `http://` schema.

If you only want to target specifically `http://` and `https://`-prefixed pages, simply add the definition to the `matches` parameter:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "CustomizeMore",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Customize contents on a webpage!",

  "content_scripts": [{
    "css": ["main.css"],
    "js": ["main.js"],
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
   }]


}
```

---

Alternatively, you can match every prefix (not just `http://` or `https://` by changing your `matches` parameter to the string `"<all_urls>"`.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "CustomizeMore",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Customize contents on a webpage!",

  "content_scripts": [{
    "css": ["main.css"],
    "js": ["main.js"],
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
   }]


}
```

This will target pages of all types of URLs, including `file:///` URLs.

---

In any case, you can refer to the official Chrome documentation on [Match Patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) documentation page,